# Adding third party vendor dependencies to mean.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I've been struggling trying to hook up this dependency (http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/) to my mean.js application.  I'm thinking it's simply a naming problem.

The error I'm getting is: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: flowProvider <- flow

I've tried 'flow', 'Flow', 'ngFlow', etc.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**modules/core/client/app/config.js**

```
'use strict';

// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
    // Init module configuration options
    var applicationModuleName = 'mean';
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'angularFileUpload', 'flow'];

    // Add a new vertical module
    var registerModule = function(moduleName, dependencies) {
        // Create angular module
        angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);

        // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
        angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
    };

    return {
        applicationModuleName:                applicationModuleName,
        applicationModuleVendorDependencies:  applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
        registerModule:                       registerModule
    };
})();


modules/properties/client/properties.client.controller.js:
'use strict';

var $ = $ || {};

// Properties controller
angular.module('properties').controller('PropertiesController', [
  '$scope',
  '$stateParams',
  '$location',
  'Authentication',
  'Brands',
  'Applications',
  'Properties',
  'flow',

    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Brands, Applications, Properties, flow) {

.......
```

**modules/properties/client/properties.client.module.js:**

```
'use strict';

// Use applicaion configuration module to register a new module
//ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('properties');
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('properties',['flow']);
```

**config/assets/default.js:**

'use strict';

```
module.exports = {
    client: {
        lib: {
            css: [
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
            ],
            js: [
                'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
                'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
                'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
                'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
                'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
                'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
                'public/lib/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js',
                'public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'public/lib/ng-flow/dist/ng-flow-standalone.js'
            ],
            tests: ['public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js']
        },
        css: [
            'modules/*/client/css/*.css'
        ],
        less: [
            'modules/*/client/less/*.less'
        ],
        sass: [
            'modules/*/client/scss/*.scss'
        ],
        js: [
            'modules/core/client/app/config.js',
            'modules/core/client/app/init.js',
            'modules/*/client/*.js',
            'modules/*/client/**/*.js'
        ],
        views: ['modules/*/client/views/**/*.html']
    },
    server: {
        allJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'modules/*/server/**/*.js'],
        models: 'modules/*/server/models/**/*.js',
        routes: ['modules/*[!core]/server/routes/**/*.js', 'modules/core/server/routes/**/*.js'],
        sockets: 'modules/*/server/sockets/**/*.js',
        config: 'modules/*/server/config/*.js',
        policies: 'modules/*/server/policies/*.js',
        views: 'modules/*/server/views/*.html'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as you loaded the js file correctly, you can use `flowFactory` to create a flow instance. Then create a flow object and use that to refer to flow.

```
angular.module('properties').controller('PropertiesController', [
  '$scope',
  '$stateParams',
  '$location',
  'Authentication',
  'Brands',
  'Applications',
  'Properties',
  'flowFactory',

   function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Brands, Applications, Properties, flowFactory) {

$scope.existingFlowObject = flowFactory.create({
    target: 'http://example.com/upload'
});
................................................................
```

So try changing `flow` to `flowFactory` and see if that leads to any provider dependency issues.

Comment: Adding 'flow', 'Flow', or 'flowFactory' to applicationModuleVendorDependencies gives me the same error: "Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flowFactory due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'flowFactory' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."  The JS file is included in the page correctly, but the app breaks before any controllers are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an answer to this. Changing the registerModule part.

ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('flow');

to   .client.module.js

This is mean.js version 0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to include it into your project dependency 
I modified it in this way :

```
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'angularFileUpload'];
```